# ray intersect object, picking object with mouse-pointer

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, raytracing

Thank you for your consideration, as my problem is in title already I will get directly to the point:

```
UPDATE 2:
```

Problem solved. I did not transformed them into meshes, or so it seems. With the hint got from supernova and a failed attempt to enable shadowmap it became so clear, although half a day was lost...

```
UPDATE 1:
```

The example is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zBtgj/4/)

.

.

```
Original problem:
```

The standard example of ray casting for object picking using the mouse coordinates, and I mean this one:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 1);
projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
var ray = new THREE.Ray(camera.position, vector.subSelf(camera.position).normalize());
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(cubes);

if (intersects.length > 0)
{
    console.log('hit');
}
```

, didn't work at all.

After taking some time to think about it I have tried this:

```
// start a ray from your camera to the coordinates on 
// x,y plane you pointed with the mouse:
// *I also draw the actual ray on the screen, it looked perfect! :( but...

var cx = event.clientX;
var cy = event.clientY;

var rx = cx - (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2);
var ry = (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - cy;

var origin = new THREE.Vector3(camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z - 200);
var direction = new THREE.Vector3(rx, ry, -20);

var ray = new THREE.Ray(origin, direction);
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(cubes);
```

But the "intersect" variable is still empty.
Although it seems logical to work, because my elements are as follows:

```
for ( i = 0; i < cols; i++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        var cwidth = (SCREEN_WIDTH / cols) / scale;
        var cheight = (SCREEN_HEIGHT / rows) / scale;
        var cdepth = 10;

        var cube = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(new THREE.CubeGeometry(cwidth, cheight, cdepth, 1, 1, 1), getMaterials());
        // getMaterials() is a simple function returning an Array of materials
        cube.position.x = cwidth * i - (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) + cwidth / 2;
        cube.position.x /= scale;
        cube.position.y = cheight * j - (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) + cheight / 2;
        cube.position.y /= scale;
        cube.position.z = 0;
        cubes.push(cube);
        scene.add(cube);
    }
}
```

And my camera is:

```
    camera.position.z = getDistance(window.innerHeight); 
    // or {x: 0, y:0, z: 403.00000000000006}
```

I am trying to fix this for over two hours now, can anybody see what I am missing? And I have searched the internet with no avail.

P.S. I hope i did not tagged this question erroneous with "ray".

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle, also does the example cubes demo on github work for you?

Comment: i will setup a jsfiddle right away, and yes the demos do work for me

Comment: in the 1st code example you posted try setting z to 0.1, instead of 1
i've exactly the same code running this is the only difference and it works for me

Comment: the jsfiddle is up, and @supernova where exactly to set z to 0.1, for cubes...?

Comment: var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.1)

Comment: @supernova, it didn't make a difference

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B3qBc/1/ i forked your fiddle here

Comment: @supernova Yes, indeed, I just figured that out a minute ago, in order for them to work, they must be meshes, isn't that so? Thank you very much for your kindness. Problem solved.

Comment: yes, to get intersects you have to provide meshes because three uses a point in triangle algorythm to calculate the intersects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16880/discussion-between-khael-and-supernova)